# Detect limit exceeded message in php xml response?

Tags: php, xml

```
     <Error xmlns="urn:yahoo:api"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.yahoo.com/Api/V1/error.xsd">
      The following errors were detected:
    <Message>limit exceeded</Message>
  </Error>


$geocodeURLHomexml = file_get_contents('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' . urlencode($queryhome) . '&format=xml');
```

If it shows a exceeded message i want to run the google api instead how to do that in PHP

**Please help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what you're asking, so I am making a guess here:
This is how to extract the `<Message>` from the XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$msg = (string)$xml[0]->Message[0];
```

or simply

```
$msg = (string)$xml->Message; //thanks to cbuckley!
```

Then you can check `$msg`and do what you please:

```
if ($msg == "limit exceeded") {
    echo "foo: $msg";
} else {
    echo "bar: $msg";
}
```

See it in action: https://eval.in/128932

Comment: It's probably neater without the array access: `$msg = (string) $xml->Message;`

Comment: @cbuckley: in case there is more than one `<error>` or `<Message>`, I want to make sure...

Comment: Well, there'll never be more than one root node, but I can see your point. However the rate limiting response is always the same: http://developer.yahoo.com/search/rate.html. It would probably be better to check if `$xml->getName() == 'Error'` and handle errors from there.